# AngularJs. Разбор , отрисовка форм и отправка запроса на контроллер из URL

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

Как на основании урла смоделировать заполнение формы и отправку запроса на контроллер.

Например есть урл вида `http://myurl/page1?param1=value1&param2=value2`

Ввожу этот урл в браузер и должны открыться страница `page1`,
переменные `param1` и `param2` заполниться значениями `value1` и `value2` (инпуты примут значения `ng-model`) и после этого должен улететь запрос с этими параметры, как будто пользователь нажал кнопку отправить и получить контент от контроллера.

Пните пож в нужном направлении

Comment: что за контроллер имеется ввиду?

Comment: $http.get(); Который будет лететь на springMVC контроллер

Comment: так в чем проблема взять эти параметры и запустить этот запрос?

Comment: $location & $location.search()

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался, сделал через $location   http://codepen.io/stoxa/pen/vLwqGg